# Is ABI in a smart contract necessary for making the front end of a dapp so that people could interact with a smart contract?

Tags: solidity

I deployed a smart contract on third web but I did not ABI into it. On the explorer page the functionality of the smart contract is not visible on third web's dashboard. Can I still use the same deployed smart contract for building my dapp? Or should I start again from scratch?

I was expecting functionality of smart contract in third web but it did not show any thing in the explore page after I deployed my smart contract.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve]. There is no programming question here, just a general opinion-seeking question.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain the ABI's role. In the context of decentralized applications (dApps), the ABI is essential for interacting with a smart contract. The ABI acts as the bridge between two binary program modules, in this case, your front-end application and the deployed smart contract on the blockchain.

Without the ABI, your front-end wouldn't know how to structure calls to the contract's functions, what data types to use, or how to interpret the data returned from function calls.

So, if you've deployed a contract without saving its ABI, you'll generally have trouble integrating it into a dApp. That said, the ABI is generated when you compile the smart contract, not when you deploy it. If you still have access to the original source code of the smart contract, you can re-compile it to obtain the ABI, without having to redeploy the contract. Many development tools and environments, like Truffle or Remix, make it easy to extract the ABI upon compilation.

Let's simulate an ABI save.

I am assuming that you have smart contract like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    uint256 public myVariable;

    function setVariable(uint256 _myVariable) public {
        myVariable = _myVariable;
    }

    function getVariable() public view returns (uint256) {
        return myVariable;
    }
}
```

**Compiling the smart contract:**

```
truffle compile
```

When you run this command, Truffle will create a JSON file in the build/contracts directory that includes the ABI, among other things.

**Deploying the smart contract:**

```
truffle migrate --network name_of_your_network
```

You can deploy your smart contract to the network of your choice or local blockchain for testing.

**Saving the ABI:**

```
const myContractJSON = require("./build/contracts/MyContract.json");
const myContractABI = myContractJSON.abi;
const myContractAddress = "0x..."; // Replace with your deployed address
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractABI, myContractAddress);
```

Now you can use this ABI (myContractABI) to interact with your deployed smart contract using libraries like Web3.js or Ethers.js.

**Initializing Web3 on Frontend**

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

This is the place you will provide the URL pointing to an Ethereum node that can read from the live blockchain or whichever network you're targeting. I have put http://localhost:8545. This can be used for local development while running a local Ethereum node.  You can use alternatives:

```
// const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_API_KEY"));
// const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://your-ethereum-node.org:8545"));
```

**Reading Data From the Contract**

```
myContract.methods.getVariable().call().then(console.log);
```

**Writing Data to the Contract**

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

myContract.methods.setVariable(5).send({ from: accounts[0] })
  .then(receipt => console.log(receipt));
```

**Note 1:** If you're deploying manually, say using Remix IDE, you will find the ABI under the 'Compile' tab after you've compiled your smart contract. You can then copy this ABI and use it in your frontend code.

**Note 2:** Remember, you need to keep track of both the ABI and the contract's deployed address to interact with it from your dApp. I have put the example on the "Saving the ABI" step.

Comment: FYI the OP asked no programming question. You wrote 100% of any code and any other detail. *Please don't do this.* There is literally no programming question, and no need to write a blog post for a generic question seeking opinions and general information.

Comment: Note that there is already a comment that was auto-generated several days ago, explaining to the OP that they needed to edit to be specific. At this point, there is nothing to answer.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMakogon As I said on the other comment, I mostly write answers for the problems that I struggled before. I will be more careful.

Comment: right - the issue is that a ton of broad, general questions get posted, and they are not really helpful to Stack Overflow (and usually get closed fairly quickly). Plus, this site is not intended as a free coding resource. It's for specific programming problems.